# Does civicrm support mysql sockets?

Tags: mysql

My wordpress is installed and uses localhost:/run/mysqld/mysqld/socket
but civicrm only works if I point to localhost

Is there a way to install civicrm through file socket ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the DSN in the civicrm.settings.php file using this format:

`mysqli://user:password@unix(/path/to/socket)/databasename`

Use the actual word "unix" in the string to indicate sockets.

Comment: for sure your guidance help, however, as StackExchange members are picky, it could not being accepted as the right answer because you forget to mention the password such as: `mysql://user:password@unix(/path/to/socket)/databasename`.

Comment: You're right I've updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: cv, the command line of CiviCRM don't like it

Comment: Can you post that as a separate question, and include the error message.

Answer (score 2):

I believe CiviCRM does support UNIX sockets, yes. If your hostname is "localhost" and there's no port configured, MySQL defaults to a UNIX socket connection.

```
$ grep DSN sites/default/civicrm.settings.php
  define('CIVICRM_UF_DSN', 'mysql://vagrant:vagrant@localhost/vagrant?new_link=true');
  define('CIVICRM_DSN', 'mysql://vagrant:vagrant@localhost/vagrant?new_link=true');
```

And for me, `cv` works fine with this configuration:

```
$ cv api3 Contact.get
{
    "is_error": 0,
    "version": 3,
    "count": 25,
    "values": {
        "202": {
            "contact_id": "202",
            "contact_type": "Individual",
```

I did notice on a recent (Drupal, web UI) installation that CiviCRM defaulted to adding `:3306` into the `CIVICRM_DSN` value (but not the `CIVICRM_UF_DSN` setting). IDK why this happened, but this might be the source of your issue?