# Can't find MySQL server on WordPress install with sockets

Tags: wordpress, mysql, install

I am using Local by Flywheel which connects to MySQL with sockets. My socket is:

`/Users/efc/Library/Application Support/Local/run/Qv8NIbiue/mysqld.sock`

The MySQL server is `localhost`, database is `local`, and both username and password are `root` (and this really is a root account, I can even create new databases with SequelPro).

When I try to install CiviCRM 5.21.1 on WordPress 5.3.2 I get the error "Can't find the a MySQL server on 'localhost'.: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client" on the "Does the server exist?" line of the CiviCRM Installer screen. Oddly enough, every other item in "CiviCRM Database Details" is "OK" (green). In other words, even though it *thinks* it can't find the server, it seems to be able to do every other thing OK.

I cannot figure out how to tell CiviCRM what it needs to know to be happy about the MySQL server. How can I make this WordPress install work with sockets?

If I try to put "localhost:/Users/efc/Library/Application Support/Local/run/Qv8NIbiue/mysqld.sock" in the MySQL server field, then "Does server exist" is "OK" but almost everything else goes red.

Note, there are answers to similar questions for folks who have come far enough along in the install process to have a `civicrm.settings.php` file. But at this stage of the WordPress version's bootstrap it has *not* yet successfully installed, there is no settings file. This question is about how to respond to this error so that the WordPress version of CiviCRM can be installed in the first place.

Comment: See also https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31343/does-civicrm-support-mysql-sockets

Comment: Sorry didn't see this from Demerit - posted same thing as an answer

Comment: @parvez-saleh No worries - sometimes I wish stackexchange was more like the old forums.

Comment: I'm really interested in learning how to do this in the WordPress install of CiviCRM, I cannot find any civicrm.settings.php file in this version, maybe because the "install" has not been able to take place due to the error I documented above.

Comment: So you're saying you still get an error on the web page installer screen when you use the "unix(path/to/socket)" format?

Comment: Yes @demerit, any variation of that still leads to errors. But I must say, it is not at all obvious what would be the right way to use this "unix(path/to/socket)" format. The CiviCRM Installer screen in WordPress provides only four fields labeled as follows: server, username, password, and database. These are filled in with the information found in the WordPress configuration, and this leads to the error as described above. Any other variation of the server entry (like changing `localhost` to `unix(/Users/efc/Library/Application Support/Local/run/Qv8NIbiue/mysqld.sock)` leads to more errors.

Answer (score 0):

Checking out other Stackexchange answers, looks like something along these lines should work

You can set the DSN in the civicrm.settings.php file using this format:

mysqli://user:password@unix(/path/to/socket)/databasename

Use the actual word "unix" in the string to indicate sockets.

For Reference [this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31343/does-civicrm-support-mysql-sockets) is the previous answer

Comment: I've seen a reference to a civicrm.settings.php file but see no such thing in my WordPress installation. Does that file only appear _after_ CiviCRM has been "installed"?

Comment: Have you tried /wp-content/upload/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Parvez, I have the uploads/civicrm directory, but nothing is in that directory. I think this is because CiviCRM has never installed itself properly, due to the error I describe in my question.